# Here-Maps - ios - Installing Voice Packages

Tags: ios, here-api, voice

I try to install a specific voice package with the help of the documentation. But installation not works for me.

PS: For one time installation was successfull. But after clean & run the project again from, the newly added package was removed and only default US lang. presents.

```
let voiceCatalog: NMAVoiceCatalog = NMAVoiceCatalog.sharedInstance()!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
       voiceCatalog.delegate = self            
       voiceCatalog.update()
       let voice = voiceCatalog.voicePackage(withId: 218)
       voiceCatalog.installVoicePackage(voice!)
 }
```

And the delegates:

```
extension ActiveRouteViewController: NMAVoiceCatalogDelegate {
    func voiceCatalog(_ voiceCatalog: NMAVoiceCatalog, didUpdate error: Error?) {
        print(error)
        print(voiceCatalog.installedVoicePackages)
    }

    func voiceCatalog(_ voiceCatalog: NMAVoiceCatalog, didUpdateDownloadProgress progress: Float, for package: NMAVoicePackage) {
        print(progress)
    }

    func voiceCatalog(_ voiceCatalog: NMAVoiceCatalog, didUpdateUncompressProgress progress: Float, for package: NMAVoicePackage) {
        print(progress)
    }

    func voiceCatalog(_ voiceCatalog: NMAVoiceCatalog, didInstallPackage package: NMAVoicePackage, withError error: Error?) {
        for package in voiceCatalog.voicePackages {
            print(package.name)
        }

        print(error)
    }
}
```

I set the language for navigation:

```
let voice = voiceCatalog.voicePackage(withId: 218)
navManager.voicePackage = voice
navManager.startTurnByTurnNavigation(currentRoute!)
```

None of the delegate functions and are called except `didUpdate` and it did not return any error.

I have a premium account and I set the keys correctly.

Comment: Did you try to install the voice in the catalog update callback ? I wonder a bit why you call the catalog update, don't wait for the catalog update and install the voice immediately with a hardcoded voice id. while the hardcoded voice id might be still ok (there are normally no changed on the IDs), you should at least wait for the catalog update 'didUpdate' before installing the voice, or not checking for updates at all if a catalog is already present (anyway good practice).

Comment: Yes you are correct. The issue is in my logic. Voice installed correctly after I try to install it after update completed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to install the voice in the catalog update callback

> optional public func audioManager(_ audioManager: NMAAudioManager!,
>   shouldPlay output: NMAAudioOutput!) -> Bool